# Understanding import statements in known Python packages

Tags: python, package, python-import

Some of the small projects I've created have this directory structure:

```
my_project/
  ├─ docs/
  ├─ code/
  │    ├─ __init__.py
  │    ├─ main.py
  │    └─ tools.py
  ├─ README
  └─ .gitignore
```

and in `main.py` I use the following absolute import statement to import the `tool()` function from the `tools.py` module:

```
from tools import tool
```

When I looked at a source code of some well-known (and probably also well written) packages, I have found a similar structure but a different style of absolute import statements:

([Django](https://github.com/django/django), /django/core/paginator.py)

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property
from django.utils.inspect import method_has_no_args
```

Why is the parent `django` directory included in the import statement? And is it a preferred way how to import modules? When I apply the logic to my project and change import of the `tool()` function like this:

```
from code.tests import test
```

and then run the following command in terminal:

```
python3 main.py
```

it raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` of course.

I would like to understand why these packages use this style of import statements (which is different from mine and does not work for my own projects). I'm still learning Python so also some links to read are well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not referencing the local directory as you assumed, but the actual module itself in its installed path.

When you have installed the module it will be accessible to your Python interpreter as `django` so it's basically referencing where the module is installed.  The interpret is basically trying to do:

1. is there a `django` path in my current working directory?
2. if not, is there a `django` path I can reference in my environment paths?
3. if not, throw a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Following this logic, the package used absolute import because `paginator.py` is located in the `django/core` path and therefore doesn't have access to the `django/utils` path unless it directly references itself as an installed module from `site-packages` or using a relative import (`from ..utils.functional import cached_property`, etc).  [This link has some more details.](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

To compare apples to apples in your case - try having a `test.py` module under `my_project/utils`.  You'll notice you will have trouble accessing that module under `main.py` without absolute or relative import because Python Interpreter only knows your current working directory (`core`, assuming you're running `main.py` directly, or wherever you're actually executing your interpreter) and any other module directories accessible via your environment paths.

Comment: Thank you! It's much clearer now. Just a side question - I've also found some packages ( [/flask/views.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/flask/views.py), [/requests/utils.py](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/utils.py) ) that use relative imports. I guess this is the example of referencing the local directory?

Comment: Yes, the `from .x import y` or `from . import x` statements are relative imports.  The dot/period means to import from where the file is.  Here's a link with more details from a quick search: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Actually I was unaware you can access the upper folder levels as well until I went through the link I provided.  I've updated the answer with the relative method as well.  I'm guessing in this case it's just a matter of preference whether to use absolute or relative import, but either one will have to be used if the module sits outside of the immediate directory.